# Map generic JSON object to Map interface with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Given the following JSON object

```
{
   "id": 5,
   "data: { ... }
}
```

Is it possible to map this to the following POJO?

```
class MyEntity {
    int id;
    Map<String, Object> data;
}
```

Because I would like to leave the data object open ended. Is this even possible or what is a better approach to go about this? I am doing this on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any idea about Android application but you can achieve it using [Gson](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) library easily.

- The JSON that is used in your post is not valid. It might be a typo. Please validate it here on [JSONLint - The JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/)
- Simply use [Gson#fromJson(String, Class)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) method to convert a JSON string into the object of passed class type.
- Remember the name of instance member must be exactly same (case-sensitive) as defined in JSON string as well. Read more about [JSON Field Naming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)
- Use [GsonBuilder#setPrettyPrinting()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setPrettyPrinting%28%29) that configures Gson to output Json that fits in a page for pretty printing.

Sample code:

```
String json = "{\"id\": 5,\"data\": {}}";
MyEntity myEntity = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyEntity.class);

String prettyJsonString = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(myEntity);
System.out.println(prettyJsonString);
```

output:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "data": {}
}
```